# Check a checkbox by clicking a Bootstrap Table Cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Using only CSS on a Bootstrap Table.** (Some JavaScript if there is no other simple way)

How can I get the `<label>` element for a checkbox to completely fill the table cell?

Bootstrap has a padding of 8px, but I don't want to disrupt that padding for the other cells, and also keep the table responsive.

Example:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add custom css style remove padding

Answer (score 1):

Add class to that specific `td` and apply custom css for label and td:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #898989;
}
.labeled {
  padding: 0;
}
.labeled label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 200, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <td class="labeled">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      Other TD
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer of @Justinas is more elegant imo, you can also do it without altering classes:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #898989;
}

td > label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -8px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 200, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      Other TD
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```